# Linq group by in sum column from with where clause

Tags: entity-framework, linq

```
public class PowerPlantsBudgetUsage
    {
         public int  PowerPlantID { get; set; }
   public int TotalWork { get; set; }
    public int ElectricalWorkNo { get; set; }
    public int MechanicalWorkNo { get; set; }
    public int CivilWorkNo { get; set; }
    public int AdminWorkNo { get; set; }
    public int VehicleWorkNo { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")] 
    public decimal ElectricalBudgetOnly { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public string PowerPlantName { get; set; }
    }

 public IActionResult Total()
        {
             var query = _context.REHPData.Include(r => r.PowerPlants).Include(r => r.WorkCategories).GroupBy(r => r.PowerPlantID).Select(s => new PowerPlantsBudgetUsage
        {
            PowerPlantID = s.Key,
            PowerPlantName = s.Select(p => p.PowerPlants.PowerPlantName).First(),
            TotalWork = s.Count(),
            ElectricalWorkNo = s.Count(x => x.WorkCategoriesID == 1),
            MechanicalWorkNo = s.Count(x => x.WorkCategoriesID == 2),
            CivilWorkNo = s.Count(x => x.WorkCategoriesID == 3),
            AdminWorkNo = s.Count(x => x.WorkCategoriesID == 4),
            VehicleWorkNo = s.Count(x => x.WorkCategoriesID == 6),
            Total = s.Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
            ElectricalBudgetOnly = s.Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount).Where(x=>x.WorkCategoriesID==1) /*this column result is s.Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount).Where(WorkCategoriesID == 1)  */

        }).ToList();
        return View(query);

        }
```

my problems is ElectricalBudgetOnly  is sum from ApprovedAmount where CategoriesID == 1
powrplantname is test test test test test so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that you have it swapped.

```
//...
ElectricalBudgetOnly = s.Where(x => x.WorkCategoriesID == 1).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount)
```

Apply the where first and then sum the result of the where

Comment: Please help me sir last comment i wanted and simple query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47987400/how-to-relationship-tables-in-groupby-and-sum-row-and-column-and-where-asp-rout?noredirect=1#comment83158610_47987400